# Can EIA232 communication be implemented using a Resource Adapter in Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-native-interface, jca, can-bus

The question may be already present here on SO, in this case please apologize my not having been able to find it. I'm planning to rewrite a desktop application whose communication layer is currently implemented invoking methods (functions) in a CAN device driver's .dll file.

However the application would be rewritten as a Java enterprise app using JCA. Is it possible to wrap the communication layer in a JCA Resource Adapter, so it can still communicate with the device via the .dll file from inside the .ear, or I need to implement a standalone Java SE service for that?

Update: looks like I indeed need to wrap the communication layer inside a standalone Java SE service that can be called from the Business Logic layer. The good news is that no Resource Adapter is needed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll need to put the communication layer in a desktop service that will be called from the enterprise application.